# Query and Cleanup Running Applications in GNOME

Tags: gnome, gnome3, application

I have managed to put my user session (GNOME 3) into a state where the running applications list contains an entry which I don't believe exists. By this, I mean that the Applications bar has the active indicator (blue underline in my session) for a particular application, and when I select that item, GNOME switches to a particular Workspace, the same Workspace every time, and though I see no window for that application, after a short while, GNOME prompts me with the `"[Application]" is not responding` window. But, even if I select `Force Quit`, the application entry never loses its active indication.

I can't find any match that I would recognize in `ps -u USER` or `killall [TAB completion]`, which leads me to believe that the process no longer is running, but that GNOME still believes that it is. Though I am sure that I could log out and the running status would clear itself, which tools can I use to query my GNOME session to identify the application information and even gracefully clean up the issue without logging out?

Comment: Feel free to correct my terminology as I don't know the proper terms for some of these things I'm describing.

Comment: run `top`. That will show what user applications are actually running and their PIDs.

Comment: That is my answer. Not worth posting as such due to its brevity.

Comment: The purpose of the StackExchange network is to answer questions, so if you have an answer, however brief, you should post it as an answer.